# Windows Forms - dataGridView column is behaving unexpected

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` with a few columns that I've arranged according to the order they must appear. However in Visual Studio 2010 in the design view I get this :

[image]

But when I start the project i debug mode I see this :

[image]

As yo can see the `Delete` column has moved. I don't know why. I tried different scenarios like editing the grid myself and moving the `Delete` column somewhere else but with no  effect. I use a dummy class to get this empty row of data if this somehow has impact on the behavior of this column.

P.S

I tried to clean the solution and rebuild, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but did you try closing and opening the designer?

Comment: Yes I do. Just right now.

Comment: Did you try changing the Index of the column in the code maybe?

Comment: I ofcpurse meant DisplayIndex....